# Is the usage of discretion correct in following sentence?

Tags: word-usage

> The players can use their **discretion** in finishing the tasks.

Is this correct usage? Is the sentence correct grammatically?

Following is the definition, which I based my sentence

> **Discretion** - The freedom to decide what should be done in a particular situation.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! This sentence looks correct, however it depends on the context. Could you give the sentence that comes before this one?

Comment: Needs more context. Yes, it could be fine, but on it's own it doesn't tell us what that discretion may encompass. Can they decide in which order to complete them? Whether they need to complete them at all? ...

Comment: @Aric & Tetsujin Thanks. The answer from Jeff is the context I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is correct grammatically.

A really careful writer would note, however, that the sentence is potentially ambiguous because "discretion" is singular whereas the subject is plural as are the tasks. Do you mean

**The players jointly have discretion on how best to finish the tasks**

or

**Each player has discretion on how best to finish that player's tasks.**

Either meaning is possible in your proposed sentence. Of course, which meaning is intended may be perfectly clear in context.

Comment: Yes, this is what I had in mind for the context. Thanks